# Bad Request when trying POST in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, get

I have quite simple system: ASP .NET Core server which is hosted on *domain.ru*. In API controller there I have 2 methods:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(string.Format(@"{0}\data{1}.txt", _path, id.ToString()), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(id.ToString());
                fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                return "It's ok!";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Something went wrong";
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(string resolvedString)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(string.Format(@"{0}\dataPost.txt", _path), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(resolvedString);
                fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                return "It's ok!";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Something went wrong";
        }
    }
```

So basically both of them are just creating text files in the *_path* directory. The part that i can't understand is when I try to call Get method by url *domain.ru/api/values/1* I can see the file which was created in *_path* directory and I have response "It's ok!". That's how I call Get:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values/1");
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

But when I try the same with Post I get either Bad Request when I do it with C# or "Something went wrong" when I do it with Postman.
That's the way how I call Post

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        StringContent str = new StringContent("1");
        content.Add(str);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/values/", content);
        string returnString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(returnString);
```

[Here's what the request shows when I try to manually debug this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5wor.png)

And the most fun part. When I try to do all the same actions when my server is hosted on IIS (localserver) it works just fine! I' really don't know what I am doing wrong. Please, help.

**UPD.** Thanks to Jonathan, I asked my hoster to disable ModSecurity in Plesk and the above code started to work after replacing [HttpPost] by [HttpPost("{resolvedString}")]. So far so good!

Then I tried to send a zip archive to the server. Here is the server's controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string ImportZip(IFormFile file)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(_extractPath);
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo myfile in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                myfile.Delete();
            }
            string path = _path + "tmp.zip";
            if (Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                var form = Request.Form;
                foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        formFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(_path + "tmp.zip", _extractPath);
                }
            }
            return "It's OK! At least we've entered the method.";
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Oh no no no...";
        }

    }
```

And that's how I call it from the client:

```
        string filepath = _zipFile;
        string filename = _fileName;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
        content.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("File/ImportZip/", content);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        textBox1.Text = result;
```

Once again, it works as it should when I run both server and client on my computer. I can see downloaded archive and extracted files in destination directories.
But when I upload my server to hosting and try to execute my query once again, I get the same error:
[an example of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym1bJ.png)

Comment: Is Plesk modsecurity blocking the post? see: https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/modsecurity-comprehensive-guide/

Comment: Take out the try/catch and try8 debugging as you will get the exception in visual studio.

Comment: @AliK, I can't debug my code when it's hosted.

Comment: @Jonathan, thank you, it worked for one case. But it either doesn't work in general or I make some silly mistakes which I can't see.

Comment: Well, the only error that you posted shows that your request is hitting up against a Plesk security issue. What other errors are you getting?

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, this is the only error.Basically, at the beginning I couldn't create a file via POST. After your answer I asked my host to disable ModSecurity. When he did, I was able to create files via POST. After this I tried to send files directly (I described this in UPD section of a post) and again met HTTP response 400. So basically it looks like the problem with ModSecurity is still unsolved. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like I found an answer myself. Will leave it here so it can help someone (maybe me in the future).

**Code of the client's send method:**

```
        string uri = "https://example.com/controller/action/";
        string zipFile = @"C:\Path\To\Your\File.txt";
        string response;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            response = Encoding.Default.GetString(client.UploadFile(uri, zipFile));
        }
        MessageBox.Show(response);
```

Here we just composing a request and sending a file. The path and url are hardcoded for ex.

**Code of the server's save method:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public string ImportZip(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = _path + "tmp.zip";
            if (Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                var form = Request.Form;
                foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        formFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }
                return "Done";
            }
            return "Empty request";
        }
        catch
        {
            return "No access";
        }
    }
```

As long as I send only one file and also I know its extension and I want it to be called "tmp", I hardcode it's name and extension. You can take file's default name/extension to save it as is.
Then I save all the files in request into a chosen *_path* directory.

Basically, that's it.